# Does Chase UltimateRewards recognize Travel/Dining spent through PayPal?

Tags: credit-card, paypal, points

I'm thinking of getting a Chase credit card. Chase's Ultimate Rewards boasts 2x points on travel/dining, with 1x points on all other purchases.

I make most of my purchases using PayPal, so am wondering whether if I purchase my flight tickets via PayPal (linked to Chase credit card), then Chase's system will recognize that the transaction was a travel spend? Or will it lump all PayPal transactions into the 1x category, regardless of the category that the end merchant falls into?

Has anyone had any experience with this?

Comment: Suggestion: call Chase and ask them.

Comment: Useful tidbit: Chase's free "Freedom" card (not the same as Freedom Unlimited) usually has a quarter where you earn 5 pts/$ on PayPal (although there's a cap there which "most of my purchases through PayPal" may easily exceed).  The Chase "Freedom" product which is a Visa recently got phased out in favor of "Freedom Flex" and it's too early to know whether it will have bonus earn on PayPal also.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, Chase classifies transactions from PayPal and other payment intermediaries according to the industry of the end merchant.

Comment: Do you have a citation for that?

Comment: This has been my observation as well, not sure if there is any way to prove it outside of personal experience though.